Close popup by clicking outside made with Pods Framework
I made a template for 'multiple popups on same page' with Pods framework. Now I also want to close the popup by clicking outside the popup. Therefore I need to use javascript. How can I use the Id selector generated by a Magic tag in Javascript?
The template:
<section class="masonry">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="project-header">
        <h1 class="project-title">{@post_title}</h1>
        <a class="project" href="#{@post_title}">
          <img src="{@post_thumbnail_url.1536x1536}">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="{@post_title}" class="overlay_popup">
        <div class="popup_up">
         <h1>{@post_title}</h1>
          <a class="close_popup_up" href="#">&times;</a>
          <div class="content_popup_popup">
            <p>{@post_content}</p>
            <H3>Meer weten over dit project?</H3>
            <div class="meer-weten">
              <a href="tel:{@telefoon-project}">{@telefoon-project}</a>
              <a href="mailto:{@email-project}">{@email-project}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

Thanks in advance.
I tried what I found in this forum.

Do you mean document.getElementBid(...)?

Yes, I mean document.getElementById("the post tile id")
